# iOS 8, AVPlayer background music playing, remoteControlReceivedWithEvent not called

Tags: swift, ios8, avfoundation, background-process, avaudiosession

I want to play sound in my app (using swift) , 
in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function I wrote this

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback, error: nil)
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

and I have a `UIView` that holds the `AVPlayer`.

I used:

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents()
self.becomeFirstResponder()
```

and `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` function. When the app enters background, the sound continues to play, but when I click pause button (which we use to play and pause sounds from outside the app) the `remoteControlReceivedWithEvent` never get called!

Whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my project:
I call this in `UITabbarViewController`

```
-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{
    return YES;
}
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

make sure it can become first responder.
[remoteControlReceivedWithEvent in AVAudio is not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6843309/remotecontrolreceivedwithevent-in-avaudio-is-not-being-called)